# Why Visual Studio Cordova project always resumes while debugging for parenthesis in index.js

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, ripple

I've just created a vs-cordova application. When I ripple this application on chrome browser everything works as expected.

BUT,
The debugger breaks on end of cordova.js and index.js. The index.js is below. Break point hits the final bold area. But why? I do not see anything in output area.I opened CLR errors by CTRL+Alt+E ,but didn't help either. I do not see any error on js-output as well. The function is anonymous has no name.So the final parentheses seems fine, isn't it?

Now,I just hit F5 and continue.It's cool but I found this a bit annoying for a while! Especially for android target.It breaks the code for many places. Have you got any suggestion for me ?

BTW, as far as I noticed debugger firstly stops for cordova.js which is added into project when I start debugging then finds index.js.

```
(function () {
"use strict";

document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

    // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
};

function onPause() {
    // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
};

function onResume() {
    // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
};
```

**} )();**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an issue in our web debugging code that surfaced after a recent update to Chrome.  It has been fixed in VS 2015 CTP6 that was made available recently. It will also be fixed in our next extension update to VS2013.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. In office I use VS2013 Update 4 and its fine. But at home I use VS2013 Community and it happens.